# Flutter is initializing for a long time in VS Code

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, initializing

[image: THis is the Screen shot]

initializing is taking a long time so I cant run the Flutter default app.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade flutter

```
  flutter upgrade
```

if it not works then you install again from
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install